# How do I convert a single integral into a double integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I don't understand the process! Please give me a simple example and go through it carefully? Thanks

For example this:

[image]

How can I calculate it by transforming into double integrals?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? You can always throw in some extra integrals, but I'm not sure what exactly you are after.

Comment: Do you want to find the area of a region?

Comment: I just added an example @HowDoIMath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the integral as

> $$I = \int_{1}^{e} \int_{0}^{\cos(\ln(x))}dydx $$

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to change the order of integration in some way @science ?

Comment: Yes you can do it? By the way have you studied multivariate calculus yet?

Comment: I'm studying right now, that's why I'm kind of confused

Comment: @PalhacoPompom: Sometimes changing the order of integration makes the double integral easier to solve.

Comment: Would it be the same as $\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^1\int\limits_{e^y}^{e} - \sin\,y\, dx\,dy$? @science Thanks!

Comment: It should be $$ I = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{e^{\cos^{-1}(y)} } dxdy  $$ which is not easy to evaluate. So if you are given this double integral then you may want to change the order to get easier one.